# Php posting a posted data to another page

Tags: php, post

lets say i have  $x data that has posted from another page to my currentpage. and i want to get additional input information from user, and post both of these datas to the next page. how would i do that? i tried to give posted data as a name attribute to button but i cant get them from nextpage

as an example here my current page;

[please check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26YNz.jpg)

here $x came from first page as a posted data. and i will have one more data named="mesai". and i want to access these two in the nextpage. thats why i tried to name button as $x but it didnt work.

hope you understand what i mean. thanks

Comment: Please don't post code as images, use text instead. That code has HTML inside PHP, shouldn't work. Use a hidden field instead: `<input type="hidden" name="myname" value="<?php echo $x ?>">`

Comment: sorry about the image. i could make it as a code i dont know why. thank  you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use always code format not image for your question.
An option you can use hidden value like:

```
 <input id="howuwant" name="howuwant" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['howuwant'] ?>">
```

or if you are in php page

```
  echo " <input id='howuwant' name='howuwant' type='hidden' value='".$_POST['howuwant']."'>;
```

Now you have all two data for the next page.

Comment: this worked thank you very much. sorry about the image. i couldnt make it like a code i dont know why. thank you again